# Infinitely many equations with infinitely many unknowns

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$d_n=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_ma_{m+n}$$ then can we find $\{a_n\}$ in terms of $\{d_n\}$? I appreciate any hints :-)

1. All values are real.
2. In general I am interested in $d_n$ such that $d_n \to 0$ and in general $d_n \neq 0$.
3. $\sum d_n < \infty$.

Comment: Hint: By the Wiener-Khinchin Theorem, the DFT of $d_n$ is the square of the modulus of the DFT of $a_m$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I will try to understand your comment. Wiener-Khinchin is new to me. Could you please introduce a reference where I could read this up properly? Many thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem. You can also read about the Correlation Theorem (and the Discrete Foureir Transform).

Comment: @YvesDaoust many thanks for the link.

Comment: @YvesDaoust the relationship you mentioned does not lead to a solution for $\{a_m\}$. It is a relationship which is in general true independent of the sequences of $d_n$ and $a_n$. Isn't it? Could you please elaborate on this more. Many thanks!

Comment: It gives a simple way to solve the equation in the DFT domain.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What I mean is that we have $\sum d_n e^{-2\pi i f n} =|\sum a_m e^{-2\pi i f m}|^2$; nothing more. How could one use this identity to solve for $a_m$? If I have the power spectral density, then it does not necerrarily gives me a hand on $a_m$, does it?

Comment: Are you familiar the the Fourier transform and the time/frequency representations ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am familiar with fourier analysis, but Wiener-Khinichin also works for cases when the Fourier transform does not exist, and essentially this is the case I am in interested in.

Comment: I guess that for a real signal you have enough information to retreive the DFT of $a_m$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Many thanks for the nice discussion. By now I don't see how the Theorem you mentioned might possibly help me.

Answer (score -1):

Not necessarily uniquely.

For example $d_0=1$ and $d_n=0$ for $n \not = 0$ can be generated by

\begin{equation}
    a_m=
    \begin{cases}
      \pm1, & \text{if}\ m=k \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

given any positive integer $k$

Comment: I think  I should refine the question a bit, but thanks for the nice example.

Comment: Although OP seems relatively satisfied, I'm not sure that this answers the question. Indeed, in its current state OP asks for a way to find a solution $(a_m)$ given $(d_n)$. One is enough and there is no requirement for uniqueness.